# Concurrent selects over same shared channel

Tags: go, concurrency

I was thinking what would happen if multiple goroutines are executing `select` over a set of channels where one/some of them are shared amongst them and while all of them are waiting, the shared channel becomes available.

Will runtime handle this case and allow only one goroutine to access the channel and do the read/write?

Comment: That's kind of the point of channels. They wouldn't be much good for synchronization if you couldn't use them concurrently.

Comment: Using them for synchronization is different from the scenario I am explaining here. In my scenario, two goroutines try to read from the same channel at the same time, actively waiting by running `select`. Then if that channel has a new data, will runtime only allow one goroutine to read that data?

Comment: There is no difference. Channels are communication _and_ synchronization primitives, and all sends and receives are synchronization points.

Comment: Yes. Note that you can't predict which goroutine will get unblocked and proceed.

Comment: This is the entire point of channels. Multiple goroutines can read/write from the same channel safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above all answer it. Also you can write some code and see for yourself. Something on these lines https://play.golang.org/p/4ZQLwO9wvw